# Is the set of conjugates of a subgroup a group?

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a group and $H$ be any subgroup of $G$. Let $A = {gHg^{-1} \bar g \in G}$. Define a binary operation on $A$ by $(gHg^{-1})(hHh^{-1}) = ghHh^{-1}g^{-1} $. I want to show that $A$ is a gelroup under this operation. I proved that this operation satisfies three conditions of group operation(identity, inverse, and associativity). But I recognized that $A$ becomes a group if this operation is well-defined. How can I show this part? Or are there any counterexamples?

Answer (score 5):

Note that
$$gHg^{-1} = hHh^{-1} \Longleftrightarrow (g^{-1}h)H(g^{-1}h)^{-1} = H \Longleftrightarrow g^{-1}h \in N \Longleftrightarrow gN = hN$$
where $N = N_G(H)$ is the normalizer of $H$. So the conjugates of $H$ correspond to left cosets of $N$, and your proposed group operation $(gHg^{-1})(hHh^{-1}) = (gh)H(gh)^{-1}$ corresponds to a possible group operation $(gN)(hN) = (gh)N$ on the left cosets of $N$. We know that this is well-defined if and only if $N$ is a normal subgroup of $G$.

So for a counterexample, consider $G = S_3$ and $H = \{e,(12)\}$; then $N_G(H) = H$ is not a normal subgroup of $G$.